# NestJS missing URL errors not caught by global filter

Tags: typescript, exception, nestjs, interceptor

I have a global filter for catching all exceptions, based of the example in the documentation

```
export class GlobalExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {

  catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
    console.log(exception)
  }
}
```

using the global interceptor variable

```
{
   provide: APP_FILTER,
   useClass: GlobalExceptionFilter,
   scope: Scope.REQUEST
},
```

Every other exception within the application is caught. But unknown API endpoints are not caught and so Nest responds with its default response structure

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "Cannot GET /unknownUrl",
    "error": "Not Found"
}
```

This differs to my API contract so I would like to catch these errors too (in this filter preferably, but anywhere would do) so I can return the response in my own structure

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my own and NestJs captuared the excepetion. I created this snippet for you https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-firefly-7szknx. Somehow codesandbox is bugged and won't start the application the right way. You will have to open a second terminal and run yarn start:dev. You can then watch the application in the second browser tab (Browser (:3001)).

Comment: Your answere is a bit unclear. Please paste your code into the answer and do not post a link to codesandbox